# how to get property-exists status with IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY

Tags: winapi, ioctl

I can't find any explanation of how this call:

```
DeviceIoControl( aHANDLE, 
        IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
        & aSTORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY, 
       ... etc.)
```

is supposed to work when `aSTORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY.QueryType` 
is set to `PropertyExistsQuery`.

This is somehow supposed to tell me whether or not the property,
specified by `aSTORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY.PropertyId`,
is available from the object addressed by `aHANDLE`.

Also, it specifically DOES NOT return any information in the output buffer (where information is returned when `QueryType`
is set to `PropertyStandardQuery`).

I find with trial and error that the return value of `DeviceIoControl()` still indicates success/failure of the function call, and DOES NOT indicate the availability of the property.

So, how does this work?

Comment: The reason for concluding that the return value of `DeviceIoControl()` is not the status I'm looking for, is that I experience getting a non-zero return from query (with zero for output buffer length) and then, when asking for that data with `QueryType=PropertyStandardQuery` I get error and `GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` (1). When addressing other similar devices for the same property, I similarly get non-zero return from query, but then success obtaining the property data.  So... I guess I must conclude that something is not working as it should (?).

Comment: For what it's worth, I just learned that:
 "Either STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED or STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST will map to ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION in user mode."
and I take that to mean that both of these map to this same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, it specifically DOES NOT return any information in the output buffer (where information is returned when QueryType is set to PropertyStandardQuery).

That is clearly stated in the [`IOCTRL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800830.aspx) and [`STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800840.aspx) documentations:

> The optional output buffer returned through the `lpOutBuffer` parameter can be one of several structures depending on the value of the `PropertyId` member of the `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY` structure pointed to by the `lpInBuffer` parameter. These values are enumerated by the `STORAGE_PROPERTY_ID` enumeration. **If the `QueryType` member of the `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY` is set to `PropertyExistsQuery` then no structure is returned**.

> The optional output buffer returned through the `lpOutBuffer` parameter of the [`IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800830.aspx) control code can be one of several structures depending on the value of the `PropertyId` member. **If the `QueryType` member is set to `PropertyExistsQuery`, then no structure is returned**.

The `IOCTRL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` documentation also clearly states the following:

> nOutBufferSize
>
> The size of the output buffer, in bytes. **It can be zero to determine whether a property exists without retrieving its data. To do that, set this parameter to zero (0) and the `QueryType` member of the `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY` input structure to `PropertyExistsQuery` (1). If the call to `DeviceIoControl` returns a nonzero value then the property exists**.

This contradicts what you claim about the return value of `DeviceIoControl()` not telling you what you are looking for.

However, it seems that [`PropertyExistsQuery` **is not reliable on all systems and devices**](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?834817-VB6-DeviceIoControl-%96-IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY%96-testing)!  It can report incorrect results at times (also, when retrieving a property's [`STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800834.aspx), that can also report incorrect `Size` values at times).

The author of the linked article goes on to show how he resorts to not only requesting a property's existence, but also queries its header and data, and then corroborates the results.

The code is in VB, but is can be translated to C/C++.

Comment: *result may be output via the STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY::AdditionalParameters member instead* - this can not be in principle. this is `METHOD_BUFFERED`  - this mean that input buffer ( `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY`) is copied to the kernel. driver or io manager after this already can not change *InputBuffer* - they have no pointer to it (only it copy). `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY` exclusively input parameter.

Comment: *The size of the output buffer, in bytes. It can be zero to determine whether a property exists without retrieving its data* - in practice no. most devices return error (like `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`) if `OutputBufferLength  < sizeof(STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER)`.  even with `PropertyExistsQuery` need set `OutputBufferLength` not less to `sizeof(STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER)` (8 bytes)

Comment: When I use `STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER`, as output buffer in query, I get zero bytes returned and the return value of `DeviceIoControl()` is the same (and any error code is same) as when using zero-length output buffer.

Comment: @jsc - this is device specific. the driver handle this request. not windows itself. i for example in test on some disk driver view `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_1` when zero-length output buffer and another result when I use `STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER`, as output buffer in query. but in all case zero bytes returned on  with `PropertyExistsQuery`

Comment: This is standard disk hardware. Device Manager says the driver is Microsoft's, signed by Microsoft Windows. Files \Windows\systeme32\DRIVERS\disk.sys, ...EhStorClass.sys, ...partmgr.sys, and ...stdcfltn.sys.  I guess I'm satisfied that this just doesn't work as advertised, so thanks for the help. I got that Basic program to contribute that way but I don't have a compiler.